# How to make an reversed filling pathLenght of svg?

Tags: reactjs, svg, framer-motion

I try filling the svg pathLenght using framer-motion library with a scroll. It starts to fill from bottom side, but needs from top one (together with green point).

```
import styles from "./MobileRoad.module.scss"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { motion, useMotionValue, useScroll } from "framer-motion"
import { useRefScrollProgress } from "../../../../../hooks/useRefScrollProgress"
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

const MobileRoad = ({ className }) => {
    const [pointPositionValue, setValue] = useState(0)
    const ref = useRef(null)
    const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll()
    const { start, end } = useRefScrollProgress(ref)
    const baseY = useMotionValue(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        scrollYProgress.on("change", v => {
            if (start && end) {
                if (v < start) {
                    baseY.set(1)
                    setValue(1)
                } else if (v >= end) {
                    baseY.set(0)
                    setValue(0)
                } else {
                    if (v >= start + 0.12) {
                        baseY.set(0)
                        setValue(0)
                    }
                    if (v >= start + 0.1 && v <= start + 0.12) {
                        baseY.set(0.19)
                        setValue(0.19)
                    }
                    if (v >= start + 0.06 && v <= start + 0.1) {
                        baseY.set(0.4)
                        setValue(0.4)
                    }
                    if (v >= start + 0.04 && v <= start + 0.06) {
                        baseY.set(0.555)
                        setValue(0.555)
                    }
                    if (v >= start + 0.025 && v <= start + 0.04) {
                        baseY.set(0.7)
                        setValue(0.7)
                    }
                    if (v <= start + 0.025) {
                        baseY.set(0.9)
                        setValue(0.9)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }, [end, scrollYProgress, start])

    return (
        <motion.div className={className + " " + styles.mobileRoad}>
            <motion.div
                className={styles.mobileRoad_point}
                initial={{ offsetDistance: "100%" }}
            />
            <svg
                width="335"
                height="605"
                viewBox="0 0 335 605"
                fill="none"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <motion.path
                    d="M335 603L123 603C96.7323 603 24 593 24 524.5L24 521.027C23 453.527 73.5 436.364 112 436.364L171.5 436.364C215 436.364 256.498 409.5 256.498 357.124L256.498 353.662C256.498 287.5 211 268.844 171.5 268.844L92.7676 268.844C72.663 268.844 1.99998 258.5 1.99998 184.446L1.99998 180.984C1.99998 125.5 35.5 99.4408 71 97.1089C164 91 195.5 74.5 191.5 0.999991"
                    stroke="#309C54"
                    strokeOpacity="0.19"
                    strokeWidth="2.4"
                    strokeMiterlimit="10"
                    strokeDasharray="13 13"
                />
                <motion.path
                    d="M335 603L123 603C96.7323 603 24 593 24 524.5L24 521.027C23 453.527 73.5 436.364 112 436.364L171.5 436.364C215 436.364 256.498 409.5 256.498 357.124L256.498 353.662C256.498 287.5 211 268.844 171.5 268.844L92.7676 268.844C72.663 268.844 1.99998 258.5 1.99998 184.446L1.99998 180.984C1.99998 125.5 35.5 99.4408 71 97.1089C164 91 195.5 74.5 191.5 0.999991"
                    stroke="#309C54"
                    strokeWidth="2.4"
                    strokeMiterlimit="10"
                    strokeDasharray="13 13"
                    style={{
                        pathLength: baseY,
                        transitionDuration: "1s",
                        transitionTimingFunction: "ease-out",
                    }}
                    ref={ref}
                />
            </svg>
            <motion.div
                className={styles.mobileRoad_point}
                style={{
                    offsetDistance: `${pointPositionValue * 100}%`,
                    transition: "all 1s ease-out",
                }}
            />
        </motion.div>
    )
}

export default MobileRoad

MobileRoad.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
}
```

*useRefScrollProgress file*

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

export function useRefScrollProgress(inputRef) {
    const ref = inputRef || useRef()

    const [start, setStart] = useState(null)
    const [end, setEnd] = useState(null)

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (!ref.current) {
            return
        }

        const rect = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()
        const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
        const offsetTop = rect.top + scrollTop

        setStart(offsetTop / document.body.clientHeight)
        setEnd((offsetTop + rect.height) / document.body.clientHeight)
    })

    return { ref, start, end }
}
```

*MobileRoad.module.scss*

```
.mobileRoad {
    &_point {
        width: 16px !important;
        height: 16px !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        background: #309c54;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        offset-path: path(
            "M335 603L123 603C96.7323 603 24 593 24 524.5L24 521.027C23 453.527 73.5 436.364 112 436.364L171.5 436.364C215 436.364 256.498 409.5 256.498 357.124L256.498 353.662C256.498 287.5 211 268.844 171.5 268.844L92.7676 268.844C72.663 268.844 1.99998 258.5 1.99998 184.446L1.99998 180.984C1.99998 125.5 35.5 99.4408 71 97.1089C164 91 195.5 74.5 191.5 0.999991"
        );
    }
}
```

So how to make this logic with an reversed animation line with scroll, and reversed moving of point from top side.